# Linux server apache httpd processes take i/o wait to close to 100% and lock down server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, svn, centos6

For about 5 days now, and seemingly out of the blue, my linux server has started locking up from time to time.

The pattern is always the same as far as I can tell from top and iotop commands around the time it starts happening:

One or more httpd processes (usually one) hang and start using up 100% of CPU power, the %wa goes close to 100% and in the iotop I see several httpd processes with 99.99% in the IO column.

I'm also running an SVN server on this machine through apache and the one way that I've been consistently able to reproduce this is to do an SVN commit of new files or an SVN update from the repository on this server (I am the only one using this SVN repository). This will always reproduce this scenario successfully, but until very recently I had no problems at all checking in/out of SVN.

But sometimes it just happens for no detectable reason at all it seems.

So it seems like there is some issue with my Apache that leads it to have processes use up a lot of read/write upon certain triggers.

I was wondering if anyone could help me uncover that issue.

EDIT: OK now it's happening again:

This is top:

```
[root@server ~]# top
top - 10:56:54 up  2:59,  5 users,  load average: 171.46, 70.35, 27.01
Tasks: 328 total,   2 running, 326 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  1.9%us,  2.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id, 96.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   2021144k total,  1968192k used,    52952k free,     2500k buffers
Swap:  4194288k total,  2938584k used,  1255704k free,    39008k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
10390 apache    20   0 2774m 936m 6200 D  2.0 47.4   1:52.27 httpd
 2149 root      20   0  927m  13m 1040 S  0.7  0.7   1:50.46 namecoind
   11 root      20   0     0    0    0 R  0.3  0.0   0:30.10 events/0
   23 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.3  0.0   0:17.88 kblockd/1
 2049 root      20   0  382m 4932 2880 D  0.3  0.2   0:03.67 httpd
 2144 root      20   0 1702m  69m 1164 S  0.3  3.5   5:19.68 bitcoind
 6325 root      20   0 15164 1100  656 R  0.3  0.1   0:11.09 top
10311 apache    20   0  387m 9496 7320 D  0.3  0.5   0:01.89 httpd
10313 apache    20   0  391m  10m 7364 D  0.3  0.5   0:02.40 httpd
10466 apache    20   0  399m  12m 7392 D  0.3  0.7   0:02.41 httpd
10599 apache    20   0  391m 9324 7340 D  0.3  0.5   0:00.15 httpd
10628 apache    20   0  384m 7620 4052 D  0.3  0.4   0:00.01 httpd
10633 apache    20   0  384m 7048 3504 D  0.3  0.3   0:00.01 httpd
10634 apache    20   0  384m 8012 4048 D  0.3  0.4   0:00.02 httpd
10638 apache    20   0  400m  22m 9.8m D  0.3  1.1   0:01.93 httpd
10640 apache    20   0  385m 8288 4028 D  0.3  0.4   0:00.03 httpd
10641 apache    20   0  401m  21m 6376 D  0.3  1.1   0:01.45 httpd
10759 apache    20   0  385m 8816 3480 D  0.3  0.4   0:01.45 httpd
10773 apache    20   0  384m 8044 3464 D  0.3  0.4   0:00.02 httpd
```

This is an iotop snapshot:

```
Total DISK READ: 5.93 M/s | Total DISK WRITE: 0.00 B/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND
10732 be/4 apache      3.76 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 58.48 % httpd
  876 be/3 root        0.00 B/s   52.68 K/s  0.00 % 52.98 % [jbd2/dm-1-8]
10906 be/4 root      124.17 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 23.03 % sh -c [ -x /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/backupmng ] && /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/backupmng >/dev/null 2>&1
 2156 be/4 root      206.94 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 21.15 % bitcoind
10904 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 18.94 % mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
10773 be/4 apache      7.53 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 14.77 % httpd
10641 be/4 apache     15.05 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 11.57 % httpd
10399 be/4 apache   1057.29 K/s    0.00 B/s 43.16 % 10.56 % httpd
10682 be/4 sw-cp-se  158.03 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  7.45 % sw-engine-cgi -c /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/php.ini -d auto_prepend_file=auth.php3 -u psaadm
10774 be/4 apache      3.76 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  6.53 % httpd
10624 be/4 apache      0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  5.53 % httpd
10356 be/4 apache    899.26 K/s    0.00 B/s 35.52 %  4.01 % httpd
10795 be/4 apache      0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  3.93 % httpd
10804 be/4 apache      7.53 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  3.08 % httpd
 4379 be/4 root        2.89 M/s    0.00 B/s 99.99 %  0.00 % namecoind
10619 be/4 apache    462.80 K/s    0.00 B/s  7.80 %  0.00 % httpd
10636 be/4 apache      3.76 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % httpd
10716 be/4 mysql     105.35 K/s    0.00 B/s  5.92 %  0.00 % mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
 1988 be/4 root       18.81 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % spamd_full.sock
```

I also ran lsof -p for pid 10390 which was way up top under the top command and this is the bottom line where I can sort of see what request this was and it says CLOSE_WAIT:

```
httpd   10390 apache   34u  IPv6 315879       0t0     TCP default-domain.com:https->crawl-66-249-65-91.googlebot.com:42907 (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

I'm still not sure what exactly is causing this all to happen though?

I killed that service but %wa and load average remain high, I also stopped mysqld and other services. It really only goes down once I stop httpd altogether, and even then I can't start it without finding remaining hanging httpd processes via "netstat -tulpn", killing those or doing "killall -9 httpd" and after waiting a while for it to cycle through all those then doing /etc/init.d/httpd start

Comment: Just now I had the same thing happen again and when I checked the httpd process that was hanging on top of the list it again said this: httpd   12242 apache   34u  IPv6 874947       0t0     TCP default-domain.com:https->crawl-66-249-65-91.googlebot.com:64611 (CLOSE_WAIT)

Comment: this type of thing, first thing you need to do is look at mysqld, see whether it's running into slow query log issues or running a backup/dump at the same time you're seeing the problem. Second thing is to determine whether your web server writes to an NFS drive or other network drive (ie is the SVN repository on a network drive? )

Comment: I think I really have it narrowed down to something in the httpd using up too much memory sometimes, so the %wa was only because memory was getting used up and it stated swapping. I have now put a ulimit -v 1250000 into the /etc/init.d/httpd in the beginning of the start function. Now when I do an SVN update I see the httpd processes going up to high ram usage but then they get killed because of that directive. So the issue doesn't happen anymore but I still can't use SVN on my server :(

How can I find out if it is on a network drive and does it still matter given what I said?

Comment: Also I know it's not mysqld because as I mentioned I stopped that and even after that httpd processes were still waiting to close en masse.

Comment: Determine which folders your SVN files are in, and then to find out whether they are on a network drive run `df -h` (list all mounts) and then run `df -hl` (list only local mounts) and compare the two.

Comment: The two are identical (all vs local mounts)

Comment: my SVN is in /var/www/svn/repos

Comment: Run some i/o benchmarks on your filesystem using "dd" (see this link for how to do it: https://romanrm.net/dd-benchmark) and then run the same benchmark on a different, similar that is not experiencing this problem.

Answer (score 6):

First off, you have run out of memory.

Your VPS has 2GB of RAM and 4GB of swap. The 2GB of RAM is all used up, and the swap is maybe 3/4 full. At this point, on any system I manage, there is an alarm that repeats *every five minutes* until someone acknowledges the problem, it is that serious.

So you need to figure out what's using all the memory. Unfortunately this may be difficult.

I can see that a single Apache process *alone* is using nearly 1GB of memory. This is obviously an outlier, since most of the others use less than 22MB each.

The reason this is difficult is that Apache lets you embed languages such as Perl or PHP directly into the process, and it is almost certainly such a script that has run away and eaten up all your RAM.

All your system can do at this point is thrash in and out of swap (which is exactly what `iotop` shows it doing) until someone shows it mercy with a well placed `kill -9`.

So your next step is to try to figure out what script went haywire and ate all your RAM.

Answer (score 0):

```
 10390 apache    20   0 2774m 936m 6200 D  2.0 47.4   1:52.27 httpd
 2049 root      20   0  382m 4932 2880 D  0.3  0.2   0:03.67 httpd
 10311 apache    20   0  387m 9496 7320 D  0.3  0.5   0:01.89 httpd
 10313 apache    20   0  391m  10m 7364 D  0.3  0.5   0:02.40 httpd
 10466 apache    20   0  399m  12m 7392 D  0.3  0.7   0:02.41 httpd
 10599 apache    20   0  391m 9324 7340 D  0.3  0.5   0:00.15 httpd
 10628 apache    20   0  384m 7620 4052 D  0.3  0.4   0:00.01 httpd
 10633 apache    20   0  384m 7048 3504 D  0.3  0.3   0:00.01 httpd
 10634 apache    20   0  384m 8012 4048 D  0.3  0.4   0:00.02 httpd
 10638 apache    20   0  400m  22m 9.8m D  0.3  1.1   0:01.93 httpd
 10640 apache    20   0  385m 8288 4028 D  0.3  0.4   0:00.03 httpd
 10641 apache    20   0  401m  21m 6376 D  0.3  1.1   0:01.45 httpd
 10759 apache    20   0  385m 8816 3480 D  0.3  0.4   0:01.45 httpd
 10773 apache    20   0  384m 8044 3464 D  0.3  0.4   0:00.02 httpd
```

This shows lot of apache process in D state.The way linux calculate load average is the sum of running process(R)+ Process in uninterruptible state(D)

You can easily find out these process using top command or you can use

```
         ps auwx | awk '$8 ~ "D"'
```

So looking at the output your major problem is I/O. Please run the following command during the time of issue and then paste the output to analyse

```
sar -u 1 10  --> look for iowait
sar -q 1 10  --> look for load avg
iowait -x 1 10 --> to get a real picture of I/O
iotop --> to see what process causing I/O and its avilable >=5.8
echo t > /proc/sysrq-trigger 
blktrace --> if you want to dig more about I/O and use to see per I/O basis,I created a video related to that,hope that is helpful
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s0XSWbIF84I&list=PLckUzKjgYDgajJVYOjNztS6Q4SOho0RKY&index=7

Just to add,you cant kill D state process,D' state will not respond to signals in the case of processes in uninterruptible sleep, any signals sent while the task is blocked will be delivered to the process as soon as it returns to either the 'R' or the 'S' state (normally once IO or other kernel activity is complete).

Expert from wiki

```
    An uninterruptible sleep state is a sleep state that won't handle a signal right away. It    
    will wake only as a result of a waited-upon resource becoming available or after a time-   
    out occurs during that wait (if specified when put to sleep). It is mostly used by device 
   drivers waiting for disk or network IO (input/output). When the process is sleeping 
   uninterruptibly, signals accumulated during the sleep will be noticed when the process 
   returns from the system call or trap.
```